# how to pass anonymous delegate to webapi/service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegates

We are having 2 services like Business logic layer as a service (WEBAPI) and DAL as a service (WEBAPI). we are having Client which interacts with Business layer and business layer interacts with Data layer (service). Our DAL is Schema Independent and DAL layer doesn't hold DTO entity(classes). DAL gets data from data reader and converts into Expando Objects and return to BLL, BLL layer converts received Expando objects to DTO objects. This approach works perfectly if the data is small less than 500K, but this approach fails due to size or time out etc. So I'm thinking of is there a way to pass func<> or delegate to DAL service layer from BLL layer ,this func<> will get evaluated at DAL layer , I will be passing my logic of transformation to entity in my anonymous delegate/func<> and also some logic. My question is architecturally this might not be best approach, but I would like to know is there a way to pass delegate has parameter to another service and execute that delegate in tht service context.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a delegate across any of the formats supported by WebAPI natively. Executable code is hard to ship to another machine.

You need to solve this in some other way. Maybe you can identify methods using strings (e.g. "FilterByGoldCustomerStatus") and have the server interpret that string.

From the architecture sketch you gave it is unclear to my why you need to have DAL and BLL separated by an HTTP based protocol at all. Maybe your DAL should just be a DLL that the BLL uses?! Then you can easily pass delegates and expression trees.

Frankly, the architecture seems quite complicated (many layers, RPC boundaries, expandos, ...). Can it not be done in a simpler way?!

Comment: thanks usr. we are using Micro Services for our application, we have our BLL and DAL layer hosted in different server , i.e. our BLL and DAL are separate WEB API Projects. we are going with this architecture because we would like to have lesser and independent deployment units, If there is change in DAL layer, I will deploy only DAL Service and don't deploy BLL Layer as my DAL is schema independent. Is there any RPC invocation can be used here

Answer (score 0):

This question is not answered yet. I have same issue where the delegate needs to be passed from the UI to BL. Assume for Kendo grid Grouping, Filtering, Sorting etc you do not want to fetch all data from DL and pass it to BL and then pass it to UI(server side) and there do the required operations. Also because this requirement is not specified and is client side, you cant create a fix query for that purpose. Because the possible compositions are too much. 
What is the correct architecture in respect to performance and Separation Of Concerns?